# Mapping to 2 or more projects with common source

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to upload my projects in TFS. Below is my scenario.

1. I have a common project, which will be common to all my clients.
2. Then there are few projects with are specific to each client.
3. My requirement is, when i load one of my client project, all the common projects should also come along with it.
4. When i do checkin, changes in common projects should be reflected on all my client projects and changes in client specific project should be independent of other clients.

Below is an example:

Lets say I have a projects X and Y. In X and Y some piece of codes will be exactly the same.  So I am uploading those common codes to separate project(Lets call it BASE). Some piece of codes are specific to X or Y, Which i will upload in separately.(Lets call it X-Spec or Y-Spec) So when i load my X-Spec or Y-Spec, it has to fetch the BASE codes also into my system.

Hope it's detailed, Let me know if any more explanation required.

Comment: It sounds like you should manage your common dependencies as NuGet packages.

Comment: TFS 2017 and VSTS have package feature, so you can publish the common project to TFS or VSTS feed through build, then the X and Y project can add that package reference. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/build/team-build-nuget

Answer (score 0):

You should treat your Shared project as a Versioned Product of it's own and deploy the output as a Nuget package to a Nuget Package repository (built into VSTS or you can just use a network share).

Your other projects then take a dependantcy on that Nuget package.

You will be notified when the Package updates, and each of your dependant Products can choose when to take changes to minimise risk.